# How to properly install alsa sound driver

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I downloaded realek sound driver from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsview.aspx to compile and install. When I did `make` the compile failed with

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.o
/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c: In function ‘snd_power_wait’:
/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:1002:2: error: unknown type name ‘wait_queue_t’; did you mean ‘wait_event’?
  wait_queue_t wait;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  wait_event
/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:1008:23: error: passing argument 1 of ‘init_waitqueue_entry’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  init_waitqueue_entry(&wait, current);
                       ^
In file included from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/umh.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/kmod.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/include/adriver.h:50,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:2:
./include/linux/wait.h:79:20: note: expected ‘struct wait_queue_entry *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 static inline void init_waitqueue_entry(struct wait_queue_entry *wq_entry, struct task_struct *p)
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:1009:37: error: passing argument 2 of ‘add_wait_queue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  add_wait_queue(&card->power_sleep, &wait);
                                     ^
In file included from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/umh.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/kmod.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/include/adriver.h:50,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:2:
./include/linux/wait.h:150:13: note: expected ‘struct wait_queue_entry *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 extern void add_wait_queue(struct wait_queue_head *wq_head, struct wait_queue_entry *wq_entry);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:1022:40: error: passing argument 2 of ‘remove_wait_queue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  remove_wait_queue(&card->power_sleep, &wait);
                                        ^
In file included from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/umh.h:4,
                 from ./include/linux/kmod.h:22,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/include/adriver.h:50,
                 from /home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.c:2:
./include/linux/wait.h:152:13: note: expected ‘struct wait_queue_entry *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 extern void remove_wait_queue(struct wait_queue_head *wq_head, struct wait_queue_entry *wq_entry);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore/init.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:606: recipe for target '/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/acore] Error 2
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Downloads/0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic'
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'compile' failed
```

I still did `sudo make install` anyways, now I can't hear or record sound anymore.  What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

In reverse order, `sudo make install` following a failed `make` has nothing to install.

Then, it seems that what you downloaded is not compatible with the kernel source you have installed. The downloaded source wants to refer to a `wait_queue_t` structure, which is no longer used. Some familiar with the source could rewrite it to use the suggested `wait_event` structure.

Complaints should probably be directed to realtek.

Answer (score 0):

A driver written in 2014 for Linux 3.0 is not compatible with current kernels.

To revert the effects of `make install`, try `make uninstall`.

The sound drivers are part of the kernel. If you want to update them, you have to update the kernel package.

Comment: It did remove:  

rm -rf /usr/include/sound
{ \
 for i in core include acore i2c drivers isa synth pci aoa soc usb pcmcia misc firewire ; do \
  rm -rf /lib/modules/4.15.0-24-generic/kernel/sound/$i ; \
 done ; \
}
rm -f /sbin/init.d/alsasound
rm -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/alsasound
rm -f /etc/init.d/alsasound

But I still can't hear sound

Comment: If it did not make a backup of the files it overwrote, then you have to repair the kernel package.